# Indesign: keep size of text frame when removing text

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, formatting

I have a page which contains objects that resize depending on the amount of text inside them.

Each of these pages have a question page and associated answer page. The question page should have exactly the same boxes, but not contain the answer text.

I cannot remove the text as the box resizes to a smaller size. I assume that if I make the text white then someone could simply highlight it in a PDF.

Comment: There could be multiple solutions for this depending on what your "objects" are actually set up as. Quickest thing you can do is post the source file here and i could take a look at it (CS6 or IDML format please, not CC).

Comment: Hi, I can't send the whole file as it is huge. But I've copied an object with some text that expands it and it has also copied the paragraph styles - so this should be enough. [example indesign file](https://links.connecteddata.com/ySbfWYPU6ISMgaO/example%20for%20stackexchange.indd/wui)

Comment: This is a CC version file which i cannot open. Like i said in my previous comment i cannot open Indesign CC files, only CS6 or IDML. Hopefully you know what you need to do?

Comment: My apologies! [IDML file](https://links.connecteddata.com/rDrBRDlgQG1GaDM/example%20for%20stackexchange.idml/wui)

Comment: All clear now. Your original question doesn't reveal this, but i had an idea what the problem could have been and i am now posting the answer below so you can approve it.

Comment: I've approved the answer, but it doesn't show as I don't have many votes yet - but just letting you know and thank you for answering the question.

Comment: You should be able to see a "check" icon right below the up and down arrows before the answer. Clicking this check approves the answer. Its only using the arrows that require some more points.

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is a text box setting which automatically enlarges or squeezes the box vertically depending on the amount of text. This means when you delete your text the box automatically shrinks in height. To turn this feature off:

- Select your text box.
- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or the Mac equivalent shortcut. This should open the `Text Frame Options` dialog.
- Go to the `Auto-Size` tab and turn it off.

Comment: That makes sense. Obvious now I see it - I had assumed that the object would return back to its original size. - also, thanks for the CTRL-B shortcut - that should make things a bit faster for me.

Comment: Great. If you don't mind try clicking the _check_ icon and the _up_ arrow next to my answer above, to the left of the bullets. stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers thanks